# How to use in clause in spring boot using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: spring, hibernate

When i using CriteriaBuilder in clause query but this query not working.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery userQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TTS_utilsEntity.class);
Root userRoot = userQuery.from(TTS_utilsEntity.class);
userQuery.select(userRoot);                                           
userQuery.where(userRoot.get(TTS_utilsEntity_.id.getName()).in(ids));
```

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have multiple ids and I can pass in Criteria IN clause, but the criteria IN clause are not work.